# Python for QGIS plugin development

Tags: python, plugins, qgis

I am trying to create a QGIS plugin with the Plugin Builder that opens a tiff satellite image, then calculates NDVI and stores it but I keep getting the following error message: " 'NDVIPluginDialog' object has no attribute 'unload' ". The error appears to be in an external code writen by the provider. Please help me figure out what is the matter and how can I solve it.

```
   from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
   import numpy
   from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QFileDialog, QMessageBox, 
   QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QAction, QCoreApplication
   from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsProject, 
   QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem,QgsRasterFileWriter
   from qgis.utils import iface
   import importlib


   class NDVIPluginDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
    QDialog.__init__(self)
    self.setWindowTitle("NDVI Plugin")
self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\ndvi_calc\icon.png'))       

    # Create a file button to select the input TIFF image
    self.file_button = QPushButton('Select Input Image', self)
    self.file_button.clicked.connect(self.select_file)

    # Create a button to calculate the NDVI
    self.calculate_button = QPushButton('Calculate NDVI', self)
    self.calculate_button.clicked.connect(self.calculate_ndvi)

    # Create a layout to add the buttons
    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(self.file_button)
    layout.addWidget(self.calculate_button)
    self.setLayout(layout)
    



def initGui(self):
    """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

  

    # will be set False in run()
    self.first_start = False




def select_file(self):
    # Open a file dialog to select the input TIFF image
    file_dialog = QFileDialog()
    file_dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.ExistingFile)
    file_dialog.setNameFilter('TIFF files (*.tif)')
    if file_dialog.exec_():
        self.input_file_path = file_dialog.selectedFiles()[0]

def calculate_ndvi(self):
    # Load the input TIFF image as a raster layer
    layer = QgsRasterLayer(self.input_file_path, 'NDVI Calculation')
    if not layer.isValid():
        QMessageBox.critical(self, 'Error', 'Unable to load raster layer.')
        return

    # Set the green, red, and near-infrared bands for NDVI calculation
    ndvi = QgsRasterLayer('ndvi: (B4-B3)/(B4+B3)', 'NDVI Calculation')
    ndvi.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(layer.crs()))

    # Apply the NDVI calculation to the raster layer
    ndvi_layer = QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(ndvi)

    # Save the NDVI raster layer to a new TIFF file
    save_path = self.input_file_path[:-4] + '_ndvi.tif'
    QgsRasterFileWriter.writeRaster(ndvi_layer, save_path, 'GTiff', layer.extent(), layer.width(), layer.height(), layer.crs())

    # Display the NDVI raster layer on the screen
    iface.addRasterLayer(save_path, 'NDVI')
```

Answer (score 1):

QGIS expects another method together with the `initGui` method called `unload`, which should clean up after the plugin (remove actions you added to the toolbars in `initGui`, etc.). You can find more information about that [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins/plugins.html#mainplugin-py).

As a first step, you can just define it as an empty method:

```py
def unload(self):
    pass
```

Also, note that you should not have `initGui` and `unload` in the dialog class; they should be in a separate class (and the dialog should then be created based on some user action like clicking).